# Search for empty beds, return room number

Tags: excel

I have a database of 160 beds, looking to search that database for empty beds and return the room number. I've set it up to count the number of empty beds, is there an easy way to have a cell list the associated room numbers?

COLUMN1 ROOM 
COLUMN2 NAME

I want to search through the names column, find a blank cell, return the corresponding room number. Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

This formula must be **array-entered**:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Room,1-ROW(Room)+SMALL(ISBLANK(Name)*ROW(Name),ROWS($1:1)+COUNTA(Name))),"")
```

---

To **array-enter** a formula, after entering
the formula into the cell or formula bar, hold down
**ctrl-shift** while hitting **enter**.  If you did this
correctly, Excel will place braces {...} around the formula.

Room and Name refer to the range containing those parameters (and the label), e.g: $A$1:$A$10 and $B$1:$B$10

After entering the formula in some cell, fill down until it starts to return blanks.

If the Name and Room labels are in Row 1, the formula can be simplified a bit:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Room,SMALL(ISBLANK(Name)*ROW(Name),ROWS($1:1)+COUNTA(Name))),"")
```

Comment: perfect thanks. is there a simple addition to return a 2nd column corresponding to the empty room ?

Comment: @user3624183 Put the formula in each of two columns?  If that is not what you mean, please show what you want clearly.

Comment: Well 95% of the rooms have two beds, bed A and bed b (P for private rooms). Database is set up with room numbers and beds (A,B,P) in two columns. How can I search for the empty name and return both room column and bed column?

Comment: Also, I need to enter this list of empty beds into a single cell, preferable separated by commas

Comment: @user3624183 I guess there is a language problem.  By **show** I mean for you to post a worksheet that **shows** the layout of data and the desired output.  A screen shot will do.  Also, to include all the empty beds in a single cell will be best done using VBA